# 301 redirect after removing language directories

Tags: redirect

I have Wordpress webpage with 3 languages. All articles are in different directories, but has totally same names:

- sample.com/article1.html
- sample.com/us/article1.html
- sample.com/uk/article1.html

I want to delete "/us" and "/uk" directories and leave only .com. Is it any "easy way" to write redirection rule in .htaccess, that all "/uk" and "/us" articles requests be redirected to main .com articles?

Comment: So you never want the `example.com/us` or `example.com/uk` versions to display anywhere, right - always permanently redirect to just `example.com`? Yes, there should be an easy way, but it's not WordPress-specific so you may want to look at examples on StackOverflow such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: Yes, you are right, I never want tthose versions to display anywhere. Thank you, will try your suggestion.

Comment: It works, thank you!!